# JavaScript - Url encoding of Array type parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, xmlhttprequest, axios, urlencode

I can't figure out how to URL encode array params in an elegant way, in order to send XHR requests from my Vue.js client to my Symfony PHP API.

For example i have this GET method endpoint:

- /question/list?subjects={idSubject}

It lists Question entity items and optionally, accepts params in order to filter results by them (subjects in this case)

The desired one would be:

- /question/list?subjects[]={idSubject}&subjects[]={idSubject}

I'm using Axios for Vue.js to perform XHR requests and i created a main class that implements the methods that i want.

As the get() method doesn't support 'data' property in config object, i implemented it at the same way of a POST call and then i process it in order to build the desired URL.

This is my Ajax.js file:

```
const ajaxRequest = (config) => {
    const token = TokenStorage.get()

    config.baseURL = '/ajax'
    if (token) {
        config.headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }

    return Axios.request(config)
}

const Ajax = {

    get: (endpoint, params = null, config = {}) => {
        const querystring = require('querystring')
        let url = endpoint
        if (Array.isArray(params) && params.length) {
            url += '?' + params.join('&')
        } else if (typeof params === 'object' && params !== null && Object.keys(params).length) {
            url += '?' + querystring.stringify(params)
        }

        config = {
            ...config,
            ...{
                url: url,
                method: 'get'
            }
        }

        return ajaxRequest(config)
    },

    post: (endpoint, params, config = {}) => {
        config = {
            ...config,
            ...{
                url: endpoint,
                method: 'post',
                data: params
            }
    }

        return ajaxRequest(config)
    }
}
```

I know that I could pass this data by POST but, in order to follow restful design, i want to keep GET method and optional params can be included in the URL as GET params.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd build a JavaScript array then call JSON.stringify() on it...  then URL encode the resultant string and attach it as the sole parameter...  to be JSON parsed by your server side handler.

Comment: Sorry but i can't figure out how to achieve that by JSON.stringify() as it return me the same exact JSON object but in string form. I have an object that is like:

{
    "subjects": [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2}
    ]
}

So i need that the parameter user to query the GET method would be "subjects" and foreach item inside the array take the id and join('&') the items like subjects=1&subjects=2. The problem is that this is not encoded like an array and the last subject overwrite the previous one. It should be subjects[]=1&subjects[]=2

Comment: Most 3rd party server side libraries that provide functions like getParameter("x") and return a value...are reliant upon the convention that the query section is filled with a collection of key=value pairs and use a Map type construct to contain those pairs... which means as parsed, only the last update to the value in the map remains...  even if you use the [] the library will most likely consider the [] to be part of the "key" of the parameter.   You would need to find a server side library that would parse it the way you want, or have your server code parse the whole URI string itself

Comment: continued...   the compromise is what i suggested...  let the parameter "subjects" be equal to "['subject1','subject2','subject3']".   Your server side code will still have to parse out that array and separate the individual elements to use as you need... but at least all the subjects are easily retrieved from the entire URI string...

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string is a great library for this kinda usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation and I couln't find a built in library for this.

the most elegant solution I've found so far is by adding

```
Array.prototype.encodeURI = function(name) {
    prefix = `${name}[]=`;
    return prefix + this.map(o => encodeURI(o)).join(`&${prefix}`);
}
```

now you can use it:

```
let subjects = ["First Subject", "Second Subject"];
let myquery = subjects.encodeURI("subjects")
console.log(myquery)
// 'subjects[]=First%20Subject&subjects[]=Second%20Subject'
```

Note:

For empty arrays (e,g: `let arr = [];`) this method responds with `subjects[]=`, which php reads as an array with a single empty string (e,g: `print_r($_REQUEST["subjects"])` prints `Array ( [0] => )`).
I couldn't find a standard for sending empty arrays url encoded and you should handle that somewhere.